# Evaluation of this line integral $\int z^2\cdot e^\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz$

Tags: line-integrals

where the contour is $$|z|=1$$

if I use residual theorem $$res f(z) = \lim\limits_{z\to 0}  z^3\cdot e^\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

this limit is undefined .However , if i expand the function in its laurent series i can find coefficient of first negative power which is equal to $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$
How is this possible $?$

Comment: You can always find residues via the Laurent series. However, the limit formula won't work for an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) or any singularity where the Laurent series is infinite in the negative direction.

Answer (score 2):

The "quick" formulae for residue only works for simple poles and poles "of finite order". They won't work for essential singularities though. However, Laurent series expansion always works.